# How to dynamically set Metadata in NextJs 14 App router, from root layout file?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, app-router

I am using Redux Toolkit to handle all the data. Every page of my application has it's own singular state. State along with Metadata is fetched/populated at page load.

Now i want to set Metadata based on the data present in state.

I've already tried `generateMetadata` provided by nextjs. I have hooks defined in my project which gets the data from state based on current route path.
Is there something that i'm missing?

Comment: It isn't possible to set metadata from states as states are client component and metadata can be set only on server-side. You could've called api on server side if you're trying to set metadata from api_endpoints.